# Как взять данные в виде XML что бы размер данных не перевишал 1мб?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml

Здравствуйте как мне взять данные из SqlServer в виде xml что бы размер не перевешал 1мб. Например мой запрос выглядить примерно вот так.

```
Select First_Name, Last_Name, Father_Name from Users FOR XML AUTO
```

Нужно что бы размер выбранной данных не перевешал 1 мб

Comment: посмотрите сколько примерно пользователей влезают в 1 мб и сделайте `select top N ...`, думаю так проще всего будет, чем пробовать вычислять точный размер

Answer (score 0):

Разделите 1024 кб на среднюю длину строки в килобайтах и получите примерное количество строк для выборки. Затем запросом выберите нужные данные

```
declare @n int = 100; -- количество строк 

Select top(@n) 
  First_Name
, Last_Name
, Father_Name 
from Users 
FOR XML AUTO;
```